Que es la libreria de schemas
hace poco empece a hacer un programa con inicio de sesion y registro en python y todo esto pedi ayuda a chat gpt y me sumo una linea que dice:
from schemas import UserCreate, UserOut
como estoy tratando de aprender no quiero solamente copiar el codigo y que ande me puse a investigar sobre que podia ser o como usarla, pero revise la documentacion de pydantic y no encontre nada, alguna idea de donde podria conseguir informacion para aprender a usarlo?
este es el resto de mi codigo
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from database import SessionLocal, engine, Base
from models import User
from schemas import UserCreate, UserOut
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

# Configuración de CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Permite todas las solicitudes de origen cruzado, puedes restringir esto según tus necesidades
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],  # Permite todos los métodos (GET, POST, etc.)
    allow_headers=["*"],  # Permite todos los encabezados
)

# Crear las tablas en la base de datos
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

# Contexto de criptografía
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

# Dependencia de la base de datos
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

# Función para obtener el hash de la contraseña
def get_password_hash(password):
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

# Función para verificar la contraseña
def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

@app.post("/users/", response_model=UserOut)
def create_user(user: UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = db.query(User).filter(User.username == user.username).first()
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Username already registered")
    hashed_password = get_password_hash(user.password)
    db_user = User(username=user.username, password=hashed_password)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user

@app.post("/login/")
def login(user: UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = db.query(User).filter(User.username == user.username).first()
    if not db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid username or password")
    if not verify_password(user.password, db_user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid username or password")
    return {"message": "Login successful"}


https://pypi.org/project/schemas/

Parece que lo sacó de este articulo

Puedes conseguir información de primera mano en la documentación de las librerías. No entiendo por qué te sugirió una librería que aparentemente no recibe mantenimiento hace 10 años

La librería de PyPi enlazada no tiene absolutmante nada que ver., aparte de compartir nombre. Coincido plenamente con Mady, parece que  tomó bastante "prestado" del artículo enlazado. shemas (al igual que models y  database) es un módulos propio del proyecto no una librería de terceros. Vomitar ese código sin el contenido de ese módulo y sin contexto es simplemente, pues eso... Si al menos las LLMs pudieran citar y enlazar las fuentes... solo con eso serían más útiles y bastante más "socially responsible AI"

chatGPT "alucina", inventa cosas. SI quieres aprender, mantente alejado del bicho.
